# Is it possible to make the windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode optional?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'd like to know if its possible to change `windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode` at runtime.

What I want to do is to be able to change this to **shortEdges** and **never** in an options menu. It's fine even if the app needs to be restarted.

This feature is set in `styles.xml` as of API level 28 if I'm not mistaken and allows an app to extend its screen size to fill the entire screen, even if there is a camera notch.

I've searched this but didn't found anything so before admitting its not possible I'd like to know if anyone knows a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that programmatically by setting `window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode`; but this requires to recreate the activity, and save the current mode in some storage like `Shared Preference`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        val cutout = prefs.getInt("CUTOUT", 0)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            when (cutout) {
                0 ->
                    window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_DEFAULT // 0
                1 ->
                    window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES // 1
                2 ->
                    window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER // 2
                3 ->
                    window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_ALWAYS // 3 >>>>> this requires API level 30
            }
            
        
    }
    
}
```

You can just keep the `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` & `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER` as per your requirements, and remove the other two.

And when you change it, apply save the new one into the Shared prefs & recreate the activity:

```
prefs.edit().putInt("CUTOUT", 1).apply()
recreate()
```